# sharepoint access displaying image

Tags: sharepoint

I'm developing a webpart using SP2010 named employeeProfile.
My problem is I can't display a picture in a webpart HTML page. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

This is the HTML code:

```
<img alt="User Pic" src=<%#Eval("Photo")%>>

using (SPSite site1 = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID, userToken))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web1 = site1.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
                    {
                        //GET EMPLOYEE INFORMATION FROM LIST EMPLOYEE
                        SPList employee = web1.Lists["Employee"];
                        SPQuery Query = new SPQuery();
                        Query.Query = "<Where>" +
                                        "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Windows_x0020_ID' /><Value Type='User'>" +
                                        currentUser + "</Value></Eq>" +
                                        "</Where><OrderBy>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name='Created' />" +
                                        "</OrderBy>";
                        Query.RowLimit = 1;
                        SPListItemCollection ColItem = employee.GetItems(Query);
                        if (ColItem.Count > 0)
                        {
                            SPListItem getItem = ColItem[0];

                            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                            dataTable = ColItem.GetDataTable();
                            dataTable.Columns.Add("Photo").DefaultValue = "";
                            if (getItem.Attachments.Count > 0)
                            {
                                SPFile file = null;
                                for (int i = 0; i < getItem.Attachments.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    file = getItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(getItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + getItem.Attachments[i].ToString());
                                    //dataTable.Columns.Add("Photo").DefaultValue = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url.ToString() + "" + "/" + file.
                                }
                                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                                {
                                    row["Photo"] = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url.ToString() + "" + "/" + file.Url;
                                }
                            }
                            dataEmployee.DataSource = dataTable;
                            dataEmployee.DataBind();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be permission Issue. Does the User have access to the web?. Use SPSecurity.RunwithElevatedPrevilage. This might helps you.

```
<img alt="User Pic" src=<%#Eval("Photo")%>SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){
    using (SPSite site1 = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID, userToken))
            {
                using (SPWeb web1 = site1.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
                {
                    //GET EMPLOYEE INFORMATION FROM LIST EMPLOYEE
                    SPList employee = web1.Lists.TryGetList("Employee");
                    SPQuery Query = new SPQuery();
                    Query.Query = "<Where>" +
                                    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Windows_x0020_ID' /><Value Type='User'>" +
                                    currentUser + "</Value></Eq>" +
                                    "</Where><OrderBy>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='Created' />" +
                                    "</OrderBy>";
                    Query.RowLimit = 1;
                    SPListItemCollection ColItem = employee.GetItems(Query);
                    if (ColItem.Count > 0)
                    {
                        SPListItem getItem = ColItem.FirstOrDefault();

                        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                        dataTable = ColItem.GetDataTable();
                        dataTable.Columns.Add("Photo").DefaultValue = "";
                        if (getItem.Attachments.Count > 0)
                        {
                            SPFile file = null;
                            for (int i = 0; i < getItem.Attachments.Count; i++)
                            {
                                file = getItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(getItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + getItem.Attachments[i].ToString());
                                //dataTable.Columns.Add("Photo").DefaultValue = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url.ToString() + "" + "/" + file.
                            }
                            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                            {
                                row["Photo"] = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url.ToString() + "" + "/" + file.Url;
                            }
                        }
                        dataEmployee.DataSource = dataTable;
                        dataEmployee.DataBind();
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    );
```